How to efficiently find the series of quasi-normal frequencies using FindRoot?
I want to use FindRoot reproducing the following result    in the table 1 of the article "Scalar gravitational perturbations and quasinormal modes in the five-dimensional Schwarzschild black hole", please see https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0311260.
However, I find it is an awkward thing to guess the initial value when using FindRoot. Are there
more efficient methods to reproduce these quasi-normal frequencies? Thank you very much!   
My coarse Mathematica code is as follows
DET[\[Omega]_, l_, rh_, NN0_, h_] := (
   zh = 1/rh;
  m = l (l + 2) - 3;
  \[Rho] = I \[Omega]/2/zh;
  (*********************)
  c[0] = Function[k, 2 (1 + k) (6 + m)^2 (1 + k + 2 \[Rho])];
  c[1] = Function[
    k, -(6 + m) (m^2 + (78 + 5 m) k^2 + 
       10 m (1 + 2 \[Rho]) \[Rho] + (30 + 5 m + 216 \[Rho] + 
          20 m \[Rho]) k + 12 (1 + 5 \[Rho] + 10 \[Rho]^2))];
  c[2] = Function[k, 
    1/2 (8 (324 + 48 m + m^2) k^2 + m^2 (1 + 32 \[Rho]^2) + 
       12 m (13 - 48 \[Rho] + 112 \[Rho]^2) + 
       36 (41 - 128 \[Rho] + 192 \[Rho]^2) + 
       16 k (-198 + 540 \[Rho] + 2 m^2 \[Rho] + 
          3 m (-7 + 30 \[Rho])))];
  c[3] = Function[k, 
    1/4 (-4 (1980 + 168 m + m^2) (-2 + k)^2 - m^2 (3 + 4 \[Rho])^2 - 
       12 m (69 + 192 \[Rho] + 224 \[Rho]^2) - 
       36 (129 + 520 \[Rho] + 752 \[Rho]^2) - 
       4 (-2 + k) (m^2 (3 + 4 \[Rho]) + 96 m (3 + 7 \[Rho]) + 
          36 (65 + 204 \[Rho])))];
  c[4] = Function[k, 
    12 (6 (25 + m) k^2 + m (25 - 44 \[Rho] + 24 \[Rho]^2) + 
       6 (127 - 214 \[Rho] + 96 \[Rho]^2) + (-660 + 588 \[Rho] + 
          m (-22 + 24 \[Rho])) k)];
  c[5] = Function[
    k, -3 (4 (81 + m) k^2 + m (29 - 40 \[Rho] + 16 \[Rho]^2) + 
       6 (491 - 644 \[Rho] + 216 \[Rho]^2) + 
       4 (-483 + 324 \[Rho] + m (-5 + 4 \[Rho])) k)];
  c[6] = Function[k, 
    18 (227 + 16 k^2 - 240 \[Rho] + 64 \[Rho]^2 + 
       8 (-15 + 8 \[Rho]) k)];
  c[7] = Function[k, -9 (-9 + 2 k + 4 \[Rho])^2];
  (*** FIRST REDUCTION *****)
  Module[{k}, {
    For[k = 0, k < NN0 + 2, {
       cp[0][k] = c[0][k];
       If[k <= 5, {
         cp[1][k] = c[1][k];
         cp[2][k] = c[2][k];
         cp[3][k] = c[3][k];
         cp[4][k] = c[4][k];
         cp[5][k] = c[5][k];
         cp[6][k] = c[6][k];
         },
        {
         cp[1][k] = c[1][k] - c[7][k]*(cp[6][k - 1])^(-1)*cp[0][k - 1];
         cp[2][k] = c[2][k] - c[7][k]*(cp[6][k - 1])^(-1)*cp[1][k - 1];
         cp[3][k] = c[3][k] - c[7][k]*(cp[6][k - 1])^(-1)*cp[2][k - 1];
         cp[4][k] = c[4][k] - c[7][k]*(cp[6][k - 1])^(-1)*cp[3][k - 1];
         cp[5][k] = c[5][k] - c[7][k]*(cp[6][k - 1])^(-1)*cp[4][k - 1];
         cp[6][k] = c[6][k] - c[7][k]*(cp[6][k - 1])^(-1)*cp[5][k - 1];
         }];
       k++;
       }];
    }];
  (*** SECOND REDUCTION *****)
  Module[{k}, {
    For[k = 0, k < NN0 + 2, {
       cpp[0][k] = cp[0][k];
       If[k <= 4, {
         cpp[1][k] = cp[1][k];
         cpp[2][k] = cp[2][k];
         cpp[3][k] = cp[3][k];
         cpp[4][k] = cp[4][k];
         cpp[5][k] = cp[5][k];
         },
        {
         cpp[1][k] = 
          cp[1][k] - cp[6][k]*(cpp[5][k - 1])^(-1)*cpp[0][k - 1];
         cpp[2][k] = 
          cp[2][k] - cp[6][k]*(cpp[5][k - 1])^(-1)*cpp[1][k - 1];
         cpp[3][k] = 
          cp[3][k] - cp[6][k]*(cpp[5][k - 1])^(-1)*cpp[2][k - 1];
         cpp[4][k] = 
          cp[4][k] - cp[6][k]*(cpp[5][k - 1])^(-1)*cpp[3][k - 1];
         cpp[5][k] = 
          cp[5][k] - cp[6][k]*(cpp[5][k - 1])^(-1)*cpp[4][k - 1];
         }];
       k++;
       }];
    }];
  (*** THIRD REDUCTION *****)
  Module[{k}, {
    For[k = 0, k < NN0 + 2, {
       cppp[0][k] = cpp[0][k];
       If[k <= 3, {
         cppp[1][k] = cpp[1][k];
         cppp[2][k] = cpp[2][k];
         cppp[3][k] = cpp[3][k];
         cppp[4][k] = cpp[4][k];
         },
        {
         cppp[1][k] = 
          cpp[1][k] - cpp[5][k]*(cppp[4][k - 1])^(-1)*cppp[0][k - 1];
         cppp[2][k] = 
          cpp[2][k] - cpp[5][k]*(cppp[4][k - 1])^(-1)*cppp[1][k - 1];
         cppp[3][k] = 
          cpp[3][k] - cpp[5][k]*(cppp[4][k - 1])^(-1)*cppp[2][k - 1];
         cppp[4][k] = 
          cpp[4][k] - cpp[5][k]*(cppp[4][k - 1])^(-1)*cppp[3][k - 1];
         }];
       k++;
       }];
    }];
  (*** FOURTH REDUCTION *****)
  Module[{k}, {
    For[k = 0, k < NN0 + 2, {
       cfp[0][k] = cppp[0][k];
       If[k <= 2, {
         cfp[1][k] = cppp[1][k];
         cfp[2][k] = cppp[2][k];
         cfp[3][k] = cppp[3][k];
         },
        {
         cfp[1][k] = 
          cppp[1][k] - cppp[4][k]*(cfp[3][k - 1])^(-1)*cfp[0][k - 1];
         cfp[2][k] = 
          cppp[2][k] - cppp[4][k]*(cfp[3][k - 1])^(-1)*cfp[1][k - 1];
         cfp[3][k] = 
          cppp[3][k] - cppp[4][k]*(cfp[3][k - 1])^(-1)*cfp[2][k - 1];
         }];
       k++;
       }];
    }];
  (*** FIFTH REDUCTION *****)
  Module[{k}, {
    For[k = 0, k < NN0 + 2, {
       cvp[0][k] = cfp[0][k];
       If[k <= 1, {
         cvp[1][k] = cfp[1][k];
         cvp[2][k] = cfp[2][k];
         },
        {
         cvp[1][k] = 
          cfp[1][k] - cfp[3][k]*(cvp[2][k - 1])^(-1)*cvp[0][k - 1];
         cvp[2][k] = 
          cfp[2][k] - cfp[3][k]*(cvp[2][k - 1])^(-1)*cvp[1][k - 1];
         }];
       k++;
       }];
    }];
  For[{n = NN0; Rn = -1.0;}, 
   n > h, {Rn = cvp[2][n]/(cvp[1][n] - cvp[0][n]*Rn); n--;}
   ];
  
  For[{n = 1; Rm = 0;}, 
   n < h + 1, {Rm = (cvp[0][n - 1] cvp[2][n])/(cvp[1][n - 1] - Rm); n++;}
   ];
  M = cvp[1][h]/cvp[0][h] - 1/cvp[0][h]*Rm - Rn;
  detM = M)

where we reduce the eight-term recurrence relation to a three-term relation by Gaussian elimination method, please see the formula (2.11)-(2.14) of the mentioned article, and we also make the k-th inversion of the continued fraction equation (2.15) of the mentioned article.
\[Omega]guess = 1.6 + 0.8 I;(*scal*)
f[y_?NumericQ] := DET[y, 3(*l*), 1(*rh*), 1000, 1];
y0n = y /. 
  FindRoot[f[y] == 0, {y, \[Omega]guess}, AccuracyGoal -> 50, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 50][[1]]
Abs[f[y0n]]

where we set $l=3$, $rh=1$, the cutoff number is 1000, the number of inversion is 1.

It looks like you try to reproduce vector-gravitational perturbations frequencies, while using  the scalar-gravitational perturbations:)

@Alex Trounev I have verified my code can reproduce these quasi-normal frequencies.  But I don't know how to efficiently find these values before  the answer emerges.
